# Change the format of a date in PHP5

Tags: php

my question is trivial i think, yet i cant figure out how to solve it.

I have a string that contains a date in the following format:

```
$date=('25/8/1990');
```

I want to convert it to:

```
1990-8-25
```

I tried to do the following:

```
$newdate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
```

But the result i get is

```
1969-12-31
```

instead of

```
1990-8-25.
```

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: Use `DateTime::createFromFormat` to turn date string into DateTime object, then `DateTime::format` to output in desired string format.

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime interface. -

```
<?php

$date = '25/8/1990';

$newDate = new DateTime(str_replace('/', '-', $date));

echo $newDate->format('Y-n-d');
```

**Output**

```
1990-8-25
```

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat('d/n/Y', $date)` would also do it. Rather than the string replace method.

Comment: @nath You have to change the separator in that case also.

Comment: @sgtBOSE No need to change the seperator in that case check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **DateTime** as

```
$date = '25/8/1990';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/n/Y', $date);
echo $date->format('Y-n-d');//1990-8-25
```

Comment: The format he's using is `d/n/Y`, there is no leading 0 on the month.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) if the original format is consistent:

```
$date = '25/8/1990';
$date_obj = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/n/Y', $date);
$date = $date_obj->format('Y-n-j');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [date_parse_from_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php)() or [strptime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php)(). Auto-guessing month/day order placement is not very sane, so avoid strtotime().

```
<?php
$strdate='25/8/1990';

$darray=date_parse_from_format("d/m/Y", $strdate);
$newstr=date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $darray['month'], $darray['day'], $darray['year']));

echo $newstr; //produces 1990-08-25

?>
```